# Getting a value from database gives a 404 error

Tags: php, html

whenever I try to get the value from the database and echo it the page will be shown as a 404 error code, what should I do?

The Code:

```
<?
$mysqli222 = mysqli_connect('HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN');
$result2222 = $mysqli222->query("SELECT HIDDEN1 FROM HIDDEN2 WHERE urlcode = '$MyValue1'");

         if($result2222->num_rows == 0) {
            echo 'ERROR!';
         }else{
             //header("location: $OriginalURL");
                    $MyValue2 = $result2222;
                    echo $MyValue2;
            }
?>
```

Comment: You don't get a 404 error getting data from a database. You get it because you request a web resource that doesn't exist.

Comment: btw: `$MyValue2 = $result2222['HIDDEN1']`

Comment: How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

404 error is not related to db. It is related to web server and browser throws back 404 error, if it doesn't find the url you are requesting. So, the possible reason is that you are trying to follow a broken or dead link.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question

Comment: $mysqli222 = mysqli_connect('HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN', '', 'HIDDEN'); should resolve the issue